# Filtering Table for Second Time by Using Dropdown Returns Nothing

Tags: angular

I have written a CRUD app by using Angular 7, but the problem is when i select one of dropdown items for first time it returns desired table data, but when i select another item for second time it returns nothing. here's my component code:

```
public patientList: Patient[];

public datess = [
    {value: '1397-11-29', viewValue: 'Test'},
    {value: '1397-11-24', viewValue: '--All Data--'},
    {value: this.todayJalali, viewValue: 'Today'},
  ];
    constructor(private patientService: PatientService) { this.getDates() }

  getDates() {  
    return this.datess;  
  } 

  SearchDate(date: string) {  
    let obj = this.patientList.filter(m => m.Date == date);  
    this.patientList = obj;  
    return this.patientList;  
  }
```

and here's my markup:

```
<select placeholder="Show Data" [(ngModel)]="datess.value" (ngModelChange)="SearchDate(datess.value)">
          <option *ngFor="let date of datess" [value]="date.value" style="text-align:right">
              {{date.viewValue}}
            </option>
        </select>

<tr *ngFor="let patient of patientList | grdFilter: {LastName: searchText, FullName:searchText} | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 7, currentPage: p } ; let i = index;" (click)="selectPatient($event, patient)" [class.highlighted]="patient.FirstName + ' ' + patient.LastName === currentPatient">
```

my second is i want to return all data by using (--All Data--) item of the dropdown list but i don't what i have to place as a value. i've written this app with material before, for that one i have placed empty value `('')` and it shows all data. but here i don't know what i have to insert as value.

[First Time Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPYf0.png)

[Second Time Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ntQk.png)

Thank You....

Comment: After function SearchDate is called, patientList is filtered and some values are lost. Try to add a new field to component (called for example patientListFiltered) and use 'slice()' method to copy values from first array to second one:
`this.patientListFiltered = this.patientList.filter(m => m.Date == date).slice()`

Comment: Thanks Marcin. You Rock!!. I've Defined patientListFiltered as an Object (public patientListFiltered : object = []; ) and That's All

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `value` for all dates as `null`, so we know, that if value does not exist, we want to show all patients.

Also as Marcin mentioned, you are filtering and refiltering your same array, you could use a helper array to solve your problem. So save all your data in one array, let's call it `data` for simplicity. There you have all the items in your array. From that one, we filter the dates wanted to `patientList`. In the search we do a check if date exist, if not, we can use the spread operator to copy values from your `data` array... so:

```ts
SearchDate(date: any) {
  date ? this.patientList = this.data.filter(m => m.Date == date) : 
         this.patientList = [...this.data]
}
```

Now when we are using `null`, we want to use `ngValue` in the template, otherwise this would be translated to string `null`:

```html
<option *ngFor="let date of datess" [ngValue]="date.value">
```

And finally, after changes, your `datess` array would look like:

```ts
public datess = [
  {value: '1397-11-29', viewValue: 'Test'},
  {value: null, viewValue: '--All Data--'},
  {value: this.todayJalali, viewValue: 'Today'},
];
```

Comment: I did not understand this part of the code: this.patientList = [...this.data]. can you redefine it?

Comment: That is the spread operator... we copy the contents of the `data` array to `patientList`. (It works like array.slice() basically in this case) If we were to do `this.patientList = data`, both arrays would point to the same, so whatever you do with either would reflect in the other. I like the spread operator, can be used with objects as well :)

Comment: I've set that into null but unfortunately did not work

Comment: Did you change to `ngValue`?

Comment: Should work: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nhlhsf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts Could you take the StackBlitz and make a simplified working demo of your issue :)

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend. You're truly a real genius. Thanks Once Again

Comment: Haha, I wouldn't go as far to say that I'm a genius, but a humble thank you :D Cool that we got the issue sorted out, have a good evening / day / morning, depending on where in the world you are :)

Comment: Thanks :) and you too.